# Reg: TINYMCE -Editor HTML Data bind issue in JS/ Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I am trying to bind the JSON data in the TinyMCE. It does not throw any errors in the console, but data is not binding in the editor. Kindly help.

Data binding through ajax call:

```
data = JSON.parse(data)[1]; tinyMCE.get('summernote').setContent(data);
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="summernote" name="content"></textarea>
```

Comment: `tinyMCE.get('summernote').setContent(data);` put this code in setTimeout function may be it will work!

Comment: i tried that alsoo not working..

Comment: May be because of this warning:A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://spelling.tiny.cloud/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Comment: are you sure var `data` is valid HTML string?